# Moving a UITabBarController item vertically

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I think I can explain this problem easy enough.  I have a UITabBar item attached to a tab bar that is on one of my ViewController's that is linked from my UITabBar Controller.  When selecting the tab bar in the view controller of subject, I go to the attributes inspector and am given two sections labeled "Tab Bar Item" and "Bar Item" respectively.

[image: tab bar view]

So here's my problem:  I can adjust the location of the "Title" by going into the Tab Bar Item section and specifying (Title) to "custom offset" and then adjusting the (horizontal) and (vertical), but what I'm trying to do is LOWER the picture that I have specified for Item from "Bar Item", and not the title.  I would actually prefer to delete the "Title" for the tab bar, and just move my chosen tab bar icon image DOWNWARD. How do I do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

I think you can see what I mean by needing to move the icon downward vertically.

Comment: A picture is worth 1000 words. ;-)

Comment: Subclass `UITabBarItem`.

Comment: It's very hard to customise this control. The easiest way you can do is to make a custom view with buttons (which represent UITabBarItems) and then add it as a subview to UITabBar view, but be advised that this is discouraged by Apple because of forward compatibility. It's possible and allowed, but discouraged.

Comment: Yeah I find this to be a rather unnecessary annoyance, but I a while back I had actually found a rather easy fix to this problem, if I remember correctly, I believe in Xcode 4.0 adjusting the vertical offset for the title actually moved the image around vertically, was a weird fix but it worked.

Comment: There you go, now you have more than 10 reputation. =] Post the image.

Comment: Interface builder lets you offset the image.

Comment: Hold on let me get my computer

Answer (score 56, accepted):

To offset the image, go into Interface Builder, and select the tab bar item in the child view controller. Then go into the Size Inspector in the Utilities Menu. Then, if you want to shift the image down by, let's say, 5 pixels, change this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

To clarify, you need to change both top/bottom or left/right to make sure that the image doesn't get squished.

Comment: gotcha. Appreciate it.